# Rails has one associaton. Prevent overwrite if the child already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is there a rails option to prevent a Parent with an has one association from overwriting the child object if it already exists?

Comment: Any chance you can use `nil: false` on foreign key column? If the column cannot bu nullified you will get an exception every time it tries to assign new model to `has_one` association. Obviously it is not possible to have child without parent then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom validation:

```
class Parent

  validate on: :update do
    unless child_id_was == nil
      errors.add(:child, "cannot be overwritten") if child_id_changed?
    end
  end

end
```